# Django - How do I save my form values via view?

Tags: django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Hi I am trying to make a new instance of a model that has only foreign keys.
Therefore I wrote two views.
In view "registerfighter" I have a table that contains two table. Each has one value, the fighter and the weightclass. I choose via radiobuttons and submit the data.
But I get

Error: registerfighter_save() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'f' and 'w'

The post info says that name and linked value are there:

name:f, value: 'Fightername'
name: w value: 'weight'

My urls:

```
url(r'^register/(?P<event_id>\d+)/$', views.registerfighter,
    name='registerfighter'),
url(r'^register/(?P<event_id>\d+)/save/$', views.registerfighter_save,
    name='registerfighter_save'),
```

My views:

```
def registerfighter(request, event_id):
    event = Event.objects.get(id=event_id)
    t = Team.objects.get(owner=request.user)
    fighter = Fighter.objects.filter(team=t)
    info = EventAdditionalInfo.objects.filter(event=event)

    context = {'event': event, 't': t, 'fighter': fighter, 'info': info}
    return render(request, 'events/registerfighter.html', context)

def registerfighter_save(request, event_id, f, w):
    reg = Registration(
        event=event_id,
        fighter=f,
        weight=w,
        owner=request.user)
    reg.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('events:events'))
```

My template:

```
<form action="{% url 'events:registerfighter_save' event.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="table" border=0>
                    <!--- List of all own fighters--->
                    {% for f in fighter %}
                        <tr><td><input type="radio" name="f" value="{{f}}" id="f" /> {{f}}</td></tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table class="table">
                    <!--- List of all weightclasses--->
                    {% for i in info %}
                        <tr><td><input type="radio" name="w" value="{{i}}" id="w"/> {{ i.weight }}</td></tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

All values posted from a form will be in `request` , to get values of `f` and `w` you have to add in `registerfighter_save` :

```
w = request.POST.get("w", "")
w = request.POST.get("f", "")
```

your `registerfighter_save` must be like this:

```
def registerfighter_save(request, event_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        w = request.POST.get("w", "")
        w = request.POST.get("f", "")
        reg = Registration(
            event=event_id,
            fighter=f,
            weight=w,
            owner=request.user)
        reg.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('events:events'))
```